# okHttp doesn't cancel execute

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask, okhttp

I am using: 
Andorid Studio. 
Okhttp 2.4.0 with AsyncTask. But I can't cancel a request.
Connected to server on wi-fi. And if server is off then okHttp keeps trying to connect, and I can't cancel it.
time outs is working but i want to cancel before timeouts

```
    private OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();
    client.setConnectTimeout(30000, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
```

after execute I press special cancel button in my api

```
    public void onCancelClick(View v){
        BaseApplication.getInstance().server.cancel();
        synchProducts.cancel(true);
    }
```

first line must stoped okHttp, second line stoped class extended AsyncTask

```
    private static final String myTag = "AsyncCall";
    public void cancel(){
        client.cancel(myTag);
    }
```

backGround in AsyncTask class

```
    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(Void... params) {

        publishProgress(1); 
        String responseStr = sendProductHeaders();
        //this performed after timeouts, and spit to my cancel okHttp
        publishProgress(2); 

        if (responseStr != null && !isCancelled()){
            ProductsList productsForSend = parseProducts(responseStr);
        //correctly stoped thread
```

I didn't forget to use `.tag` in the builder request

```
    public Response post(String url, String json) {
        RequestBody body = RequestBody.create(JSON, json);
        Request request = new Request.Builder()
            .tag(myTag)
            .url(url)
            .post(body)
            .build();

        return call(request);
    }
```

"call" is my method which makes the okHttp call

```
    private Response call(Request request){
        try {
            return client.newCall(request).execute();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e("Aync call", "IO exception " + e.getMessage());
        }
        return null;
    }
```

"Tags" is true, code in okHttp Library realy fires call.cancel();

```
    for (Call call : executedCalls) {
      if (Util.equal(tag, call.tag())) {
        call.cancel();
      }
    }
```

method which is running Async

```
    public void onRefreshProducts(View v){
        progressLayout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        progressBar.setProgress(0);
        synchProducts = new SynchProducts(activityCallBack);
        synchProducts.execute();
    }
```

"activityCallBack" is the interface I use when I call to my activity from AsyncTask class
i don't want to use okHttp enqueue, but I can't insert a friendly progress bar in my app.
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try updating the library to `okhttp 2.5.0` and use the [cancel()](https://square.github.io/okhttp/2.x/okhttp/com/squareup/okhttp/OkHttpClient.html#cancel(java.lang.Object)) method. The [ChangeLog](https://github.com/square/okhttp/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md) for 2.5.0 mentions the following:

> Call canceling is more reliable. We had a bug where a socket being connected wasn't being closed when the application used Call.cancel().

Hopefully it will fix the issue.

Comment: @anivaler Thanks. Updated the link.